# H-Bridge only low output voltage; IRLZ-34N

Tags: arduino, mosfet, h-bridge, led-driver, nmos

I want to create a LED driver with the help of an H-Bridge. I have some experience with the IRLZ-34N and already created some simple inverter driver boards with it.

But this circuit is giving me a really hard time.
When I supply one side of the Bridge, there is only a voltage of 5V between the output.

From my understanding, the 5V provided by the Arduino should be enough to switch the MOSFET fully. I also tried it open with only a multimeter as a load. GND of Arduino is connected to the GND of the circuit.

I don't have dedicated protection diodes as I figured I don't have an inductive load and the IRLZ-34N has an integrated protection diode

What do I miss?
Thank you in advance!

Schematic:
[image]

Comment: What voltage do you *want* at the source of one of the high-side FETs? What would be the gate-source voltage?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using an N-channel FET as a high side switch. You need a gate voltage a few volts higher than VPP to turn Q1 or Q3 on fully.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see the problem as well!
What would be your recommendation to use instead? My mosfet only supports 16Vgs max so I have to buy new components anyway. Should I switch to a different setup or just get different nmos.

Comment: @schoche Use proper high-side gate drivers.